# .NET library for posting to a Blog

Tags: c#, .net, blogs

I want to build something similar to LiveWriter for my own purposes, but I can't seem to find a library that will post to a blog using the well known protocols (like XML-RPC) that are supported by WordPress and other popular blogging platforms.

Has someone written a library like that?

Comment: Google returned http://www.xml-rpc.net/.  Did that library not work?

Comment: @KirkWoll I am actually looking for MetaWebLog Client API, which is typically built on top of Xml-Rpc.  I can't seem to find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has info on that: http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

The blogger API is compatible with WordPress.