# Looking for a MetaWebLog Client library for .NET. Does one exist?

Tags: c#, .net, blogs, metaweblog

I need to implement some code on top of a MetaWebLog API client library.  The only thing I am finding on google is broken links from the last decade.

Does anyone know of a library (or code) that implements the MetaWebLog API from a standpoint of a client app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET library for posting to a Blog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489901/net-library-for-posting-to-a-blog)

Comment: @JohnSaunders It is not exactly a dup (other question is mine too), but there I was asking for an xml-rpc lib, here I am asking for a specific protocol library (Metaweblog client API).

Comment: Please clarify that in your question.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JoeBlogs](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs) is a library that allows easy interaction with Wordpress blogs, and other blogs that support the metaWeblog XML RPC api.

[Live Writer Provider Documentation and .Net Example](http://livewriterprovider.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Live%20Writer%20Provider%20API&referringTitle=Home)

[MetaWebLog To BlogML Converter](http://metaweblogtoblogml.codeplex.com/) — you can get the source code and use MetaweblogAPI.cs.

Comment: I should also point out that JoeBlogs has moved from CodePlex to [GitHub](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs), though v1 on CodePlex worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Matlus (http://www.matlus.com/metaweblog-api-c-library/) has an extremely simple to use MetaWeblog system that uses only System.IO.Stream for communication. It was by far the simplest Metaweblog example I could find.

http://metaweblogger.codeplex.com/